# Random column fetch in cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra

I am using this code for fetching user_id & user_code

```
Keyspace keyspace = HFactory.createKeyspace("test", cluster);
CqlQuery<String,String,ByteBuffer> cqlQuery = new CqlQuery<String,String,ByteBuffer>(keyspace, stringSerializer, stringSerializer, new ByteBufferSerializer());
cqlQuery.setQuery("select user_id,user_code from User");
QueryResult<CqlRows<String,String,ByteBuffer>> result = cqlQuery.execute();
Iterator iterator = result.get().iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    Row<String, String, ByteBuffer> row =  (Row<String, String, ByteBuffer>) iterator.next();
    System.out.println("\nInserted data is as follows:\n" + row.getColumnSlice().getColumns().get(0).getValue().getInt());
    System.out.println("\nInserted data is as follows:\n" + Charset.forName("UTF-8").decode(row.getColumnSlice().getColumns().get(1).getValueBytes()));
}
```

Now Problem lies here that I am converting the fields according to their specific type

What if query goes random? How to handle that scenario?

Comment: Plz try to use different BufferSerialezer instead of ByteBufferSerializer , via this u will always get all data in a byte stream , try to extract out data from data base in the actual format in which it is stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CQL queries are returned with metadata about the columns they contain, similar to a JDBC resultset.

I don't know if or how Hector exposes this information.  For CQL, a better choice would be the new pure CQL driver here: https://github.com/datastax/java-driver

Comment: How did you get it to work? Take a look at [my gist](https://gist.github.com/shehaaz/5279566) ...It is a Cassandra Cluster Session...just called new Cassandra(); Fails hard...does it have to with the port? why can't I set it to localhost:9160....In ProtocolOptions the DEFAULT_PORT is set to 9042...why is that? Thanks! :)